# I'm getting an error " Cannot resolve keyword 'group' into field. " trying to filter group model in admin.py

Tags: python, django

I have a model Transaction

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
income_period_choices = (('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Fortnightly',
                                                'Fortnightly'))
chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                 choices=income_period_choices,
                                 null=True,
                                 blank=True, default='Weekly')
property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                           max_digits=7,
                                           decimal_places=2,
                                           null=True,
                                           blank=True)
```

and admin.py

```
@admin.register(Transaction)
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   search_fields = ['chp_reference', 'familymember__name']
   inlines = [FamilyGroupInline, FamilyMemberInline]

   def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       obj.Group = request.user.groups.all()
       print(obj.Group)
       super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

   def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super().get_queryset(request)
       if request.user.is_superuser:
           return qs
       return qs.filter(group__name__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

I'm trying to override save_model for each user in a group and then get a query_set for each group.
the main purpose is I want each group to access its own Transaction.

and then im getting this error :

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'group' into field. Choices are: chp_reference, familygroup, familymember, id, income_period, property_market_rent, rent_effective_date
```

Comment: I hope the error message itself self explanatory

Comment: You don't have a model field called `group`. That is why you are getting this error

Comment: How Transaction model is connected to User?

Comment: Yes, i dont have model field called groups, because if i add it. Every user will have to add group for their selfs